# InfoPath: Is it possible to allow user to submit a form, but not see library contents?

Tags: infopath

Currently using a SharePoint Form Library with InfoPath 2010, filling out the form in the SharePoint web interface. Pretty much an InfoPath newbie. Let's say I've made a form to let my employees submit some somewhat sensitive information (for instance, a form for reporting a sick day). I want to let my users submit instances of this form, but limit read access to the document library so regular users can't see other users' submissions.

Currently, forms are submitted by selecting "Add a new document"/"Add a new form"). Is my desired behavior possible to achieve in an elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be to do as Eric suggested and then add a workflow on top of the item that secures it from other users. With 2010 you have the ability to run a workflow using an impersonation step. Doing this you can set security on individual documents when they get submitted. This is more overhead but does give you true security.

Answer (score 2):

What I generally do in this situation is not actually direction users to the actual list/form.

After I create the infopath form, I create a new page.  I add an Infopath web part, and point it to that list (it's very easy if you haven't done it).

This is what I do on the infopath form.

1. Open Infopath
2. Click on PAGE DESIGN, click on NEW VIEW
3. Create a new view.... call it "thank you" and put some thank you text
4. Click on DATA, SUBMIT OPTIONS
5. Make sure PERFORM CUSTOM ACTION USING RULES is checked, click OK
6. Still on the DATA toolbar, click on FORM SUBMIT (it might have opened up)
7. This should bring up rules on the right
8. Click on NEW, then ACTION, leave the default condition (it may have already this as well)
9. Under RUN THESE ACTIONS, click on SWITCH VIEWS
10. Choose your "thank you" view
11. Click on RUN THESE ACTIONS again, click on SUBMIT DATA (if there isn't already a submit data added by default by Sharepoint)
12. Save and Publish your form

That should do it.  My directions are just a touch rough because sometimes after you choose "Perform Custom rules" sharepoint will add a rule automatically.  I've had it not do it as well.

This gives you the flexibility of direction users to a page that you can easily customize if need by rather than taking them straight to the list.

Comment: Just for clarity purposes however, this does nothing to secure your information. It's security through deception. If they don't "find" the list, they won't see it.

Comment: That's true.  You could use the method I listed for a good way to show the form but also create a new view and filter it on CreatedBy [ME] as suggested before.

Comment: I followed above instructions (editd May 23, 2012 at 23:31) and it saved the "thank you" view on my main form. Now I don't have the main form anymore.

Answer (score 1):

To help reduce the threat of leaking sensitive data, you should create a view in the form library that has limited information and is filtered where `created by` equals `Me`. Set this as the default view for the form library.

Users should get redirected to that page upon completion of the form.

If you change this form from submitting to a form library to submitting to a list, you can specify the Read and Edit access permissions in the Lists Advanced Settings so users can only see their own submissions and edit only their own (or none).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page and add the InfoPath Form Web Part to this Page. While adding the InfoPath Form, configure it to use your desired list's form.